# Light, small, low-prerequisite multiplatform IM clients for linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Basically, I need a REALLY light GUI multiplatform IM client for Ubuntu linux with minimal prerequisites.

In my current setup pidgin requires about 100 mb of extra space.

I tried a self compiled version of ayttm (made into a deb with checkinstall) which crashes when I try to log into it - I'll probably have to file an error report later, but that's out too.

So.. the correct answer would need to support at LEAST MSN, AIM and jabber, run on ubuntu karmic koala (though it does not need to be on the repositories), and have minimal prerequsites - my current setup is openbox based and space limited so I don't want anything that requires a load of other packages.

Comment: If you want really light, why not consider a terminal based client?

Comment: i'd like to be able to use a mouse with it - and handle more than one coversation per session-i also find needing to remember key combinations unique to a single app annoying. I've tried finch and centerim, and well, it dosen't suit the setup i'm aiming at. GUI is mainly so i can have seperate windows for seperate conversations at once.

Comment: essentially you are asking for the impossible. every gui-im is written with a gui-toolkit which tend to be pretty big (well, what are 100m in the days of tb-discs?) and then comes the networking lib (most likely libpurple) ... essentially, stop wasting your time or lower your expectations (aka: use console tools)

Comment: i'm running the system in question off on a 4 gb disk. i've given http://ayttm.sourceforge.net/ a shot, but its buggy- crashes on MSN connection - though its got a gui and the package i compiled is 2mb - i'll be submitting a bug report once i work out where to. 

If i wanted console tools, i'd ask specifically for them- i'd note the earlier answer does include several i tried, and why i don't want a cli tool.

GUI dosen't have to mean bloated, i'd think.

Comment: in addition - i'd note that pidgin on windows is 14 mb. pidgin on ubuntu is over 100 mb with 99 prerequisite packages.They both use GTK and Libpurple- so... its probably *not* a concequence of the choice of toolkit.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to build pidgin from source (on another box, I guess) with a lighter configuration, and make a package with that.

Comment: Thats a possibility - if the client i managed to get working is unsatisfactory, i might do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not the prettiest solution, and it still needs a little work - i helped them squish a MSN bug that seemed major but [AYTTM](http://ayttm.sourceforge.net/) seems to fit what i need, when it does work. It has.. TWO dependancies i think - glib2 and gtk2, and i needed to compile it from git, since the release version was a little buggy as i mentioned, but it only requires 5 mb of space in addition to the two deps, which i already seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finch, the console mode pidgin version?

There are console mode apps for each of the individual protocols you require, but finding a small multi-protocol app will be tough (if even possible).

There are several Qt/KDE based options, but those are likely to be even larger than Pidgin.

Comment: in my case.. pidgin is 100+ megs worth of packages. i'd be better off with running miranda or pidgin in wine at this point. seems a little silly to me tho, to need to do that. I've listed my reasons for not wanting to use finch, or centerim

Comment: Pidgin win32 is only that small because it relies on a lot of the Windows libraries (check out the "dependency walker" util to confirm).  On a bare Unix machine, it needs many more supporting libraries to be built/installed.  If you're running Wine (which isn't a small package, either), it installs a skeletal Win32 tree under your homedir to support the Windows apps you run.  There is no free lunch.  Why not use "screen" and an individual window running a console client for each protocol you need to use?  That's about the only way you'll keep a small footprint.